# Check if screen is in MultiWindowMode without activity

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, split-screen

Is there any way to find out if screen is split if I have no access to `Activity`? (Structurally I can't call `isInMultiWindowMode` method.

I see that default `Activity#isInMultiWindowMode()` implementation is:

```
public boolean isInMultiWindowMode() {
    try {
        return ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().isInMultiWindowMode(mToken);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Where do you want to check? Inside fragment?

Comment: Wherever you will go , when specific app would go into multiwindowmode you will have access to one of the activity which will be on top stack

Comment: @Jai through hierarchy due to encapsulation of screen logic I have no access to Activity

Comment: You could also use listener onMultiWindowChanged inside your activity but I'm not sure about how could you update your child class, If you could tell me about relation and hierarchy, I could help you with that

Comment: @Jai I found quite a risky solution. I have access to method `getContext()` which returns a `Context` class. And after casting it to `Activity` can access this method. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Fragment you can use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    if (((Activity)getContext()).isInMultiWindowMode()){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the only way to do this without an `Activity` is by using an `AccessibilityService` that has the permissions to get the list of windows currently displayed and check if there's a window whose type is `AccessibilityWindowInfo.TYPE_SPLIT_SCREEN_DIVIDER`.

For example, you could have the following method to do so:

```
private boolean inSplitScreenMode(List<AccessibilityWindowInfo> windows) {
    for (AccessibilityWindowInfo window : windows) {
        if (window.getType() == AccessibilityWindowInfo.TYPE_SPLIT_SCREEN_DIVIDER) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

check this method when receiving window state changed accessibility events

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if ((event.getEventType() & AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) != 0) {
        if (inSplitScreenMode(getWindows()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Split screen mode detected");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No split screen");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @alex this is exactly what I was looking for, to detect when the device goes in split screen mode. But unfortunately, the method you provided `inSplitScreenMode` does not work. Is there anything missing?

Comment: @MayurMore do you have a properly set-up `AccessibilityService` (ie. receives `AccessibilityEvent`s)? In order to detect this, your service mustn't filter events from system apps by providing appropriate `android:packageNames` attribute. Lastly as with all Android APIs, this largely varies by manufacturer implementation (personally I tested this on a Pixel 3 running android 9)

Comment: @AlexLonescu It worked! The accessibilityFlag, flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows was missing from the accessibility.xml. :)

Comment: @MayurMore forgot about the service flags as it's been a while. Glad it's working :D